# Theme CSS missing completely

Tags: themes, css

Run into a bit of an issue with our WordPress site, and can't for the life of me work out why it's not applying the CSS to the site!

Our website is https://beecityliving.co.uk/ and we're using Oceanwp as a theme, with Elementor as the main page blocks.

It looks like it's just not including the correct CSS files, and I'm wondering if anyone has had any experience with this before?

As far as I know, nothing has been changed with the theme before it broke.

Comment: the whole website is missing the `<head>` elements.

Comment: seems to be loaded now.